# common lispのデバッガーの使い方を教えて下さい。

Tags: common-lisp

環境
linux(ubuntu)
roswell上のemacs上のslime (SBCL)

和書ではデバッガーの使い方がほとんど書いていないかマイナー処理系をつかっていて、英語ページもどこをみたらよいのか。(slime公式を見てもいまいちわからず。）

詳しい解説のあるWEBや書籍はありませんでしょうか。
slimeではなくても、CLISPやSBCLのデバッガーの使い方など、参考になるものであれば、歓迎です。

一応自己レスですが、

https://malisper.me/category/debugging-common-lisp/
ここは良さそうだと思いました。

書籍ではCommon Lisp Recipesという本に、参考になる章立てがありました。

Answer (score 1):

既に参考文献のなかに挙げられていますが、Debugging Lispには邦訳があり、対話的/非対話的な使い方の双方が解説されています。
日常的に使う範囲はほぼ網羅されていると思いますので、かなり有用かと思います。
https://glider-gun.github.io/blog/2015/12/19/debugging-lisp-part-1-zai-konpairu/

また、Common Lispにおいてデバッガはコンディションシステムを構成するツールの一つという位置付けですが、コンディションシステムをテーマにした書籍も出版されています。

- [The Common Lisp Condition System - Beyond Exception Handling with Control Flow Mechanisms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4842-6134-7)

ただし個人的な感想ですが、こちらの書籍はLisp系書籍にありがちな「作って学ぶ」系の解説がベースのため具体的なツールの使い方の解説という感じではなく、コンディションシステムという概念を学ぶ方向の書籍かと思いました。